# How to convert a CharField to a DateTimeField in peewee on the fly?

Tags: peewee

I have model I created on the fly for peewee. Something like this:

```
class TestTable(PeeweeBaseModel):
    whencreated_dt = DateTimeField(null=True)
    whenchanged = CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

I load data from a text file to a table using peewee, the column "whenchanged" contains all dates in a format of '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' as varchar column. Now I want to convert the text field "whenchanged" into a datetime format in "whencreated_dt".
I tried several things... I ended up with this:

```
# Initialize table to TestTable
to_execute = "table.update({table.%s : datetime.strptime(table.%s, '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S')}).execute()" % ('whencreated_dt', 'whencreated')
```

which fails with a "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not CharField": I'm trying to convert "whencreated" to datetime and then assign it to "whencreated_dt".

I tried a variation... following e.g. works without a hitch:

```
# Initialize table to TestTable
to_execute = "table.update({table.%s : datetime.now()}).execute()" % (self.name)
exec(to_execute)
```

But this is of course just the current datetime, and not another field.

Anyone knows a solution to this?

Edit... I did find a workaround eventually... but I'm still looking for a better solution... The workaround:

```
all_objects = table.select()
for o in all_objects:
    datetime_str = getattr( o, 'whencreated' )
    setattr(o, 'whencreated_dt', datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    o.save()
```

Loop over all rows in the table, get the "whencreated". Convert "whencreated" to a datetime, put it in "whencreated_dt", and save each row.

Regards,
Sven

Comment: Why are you using getattr(o, 'whencreated') when you could just write "o.whencreated"? Why are you using setattr when you could just write "o.whencreated_dt = datetime...)?

Answer (score 1):

Your example:

```
to_execute = "table.update({table.%s : datetime.strptime(table.%s, '%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S')}).execute()" % ('whencreated_dt', 'whencreated')
```

Will not work. Why? Because `datetime.strptime` is a Python function and operates in Python. An UPDATE query works in database-land. How the hell is the database going to magically pass row values into "datetime.strptime"? How would the db even know how to call such a function?

Instead you need to use a SQL function -- a function that is executed by the database. For example, Postgres:

```
TestTable.update(whencreated_dt=whenchanged.cast('timestamp')).execute()
```

This is the equivalent SQL:

```
UPDATE test_table SET whencreated_dt = CAST(whenchanged AS timestamp);
```

That should populate the column for you using the correct data type. For other databases, consult their manuals. Note that SQLite does *not* have a dedicated date/time data type, and the datetime functionality uses strings in the Y-m-d H:M:S format.

Comment: Good answer using bad language. Please, avoid theatrical question chains, "how the hell" and fellows. Gave a thumb up anyway.

Comment: My answer, while somewhat rude, was meant to get the question-asker thinking about their question. And the boundary between python and sql.